# How to create a new role with authenticated user permissions

Tags: 7, users

I want to create a new role. New role should have all the permissions of authenticated user as well as the some new permissions.

I used the following code,

```
$role = new stdClass();
$role->name = 'New role';

// load the authenticated user role
$auth_role = user_role_load(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID);
$role->weight = $auth_role->weight + 1;

user_role_save($role);
```

and I will assign the permissions using user_role_change_permissions() or user_role_grant_permissions()

Now I want to assign the authenticated user permissions to this new role. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. following code will achieve the this functionality,

```
$role = new stdClass();
$role->name = 'New role';
// load the authenticated user role
$auth_role = user_role_load(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID);
// Give the weight more than authenticate user, so that
// New role will have all the authenticated user permissions
// by default.
$role->weight = $auth_role->weight + 1;
user_role_save($role);
$auth_permissions = user_role_permissions(array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated users'));
$auth_permissions += array('other permissions');
// Grant permissions to our 'New role' role
user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, array_keys($auth_permissions[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID]));
```

Comment: The code didn't work for me, but changing the second $auth_permissions line to this fixed it:   $auth_permissions[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] += array('other permissions' => 1);

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will assign new role to user:

```
global $user;
$key = array_search('your role', $user->roles);
if ($key == FALSE) {
  $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
  $rid = array_search('your role', $roles);
  if ($rid != FALSE) {
    /* change role in current session*/  
    $user->roles[$rid] = 'your role';
    /*save role in db*/
    $new_role[$rid] = 'your role';
    user_save($user, array('roles' => $new_role));
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 This is not what I want. I'm talking about creating a new user role, not assigning a new role to the user.

Comment: Your question sounds "Now I want to assign the authenticated user permissions to this new role. How to achieve this?" So i think you want assign this new role to user.